# Java - Parse TAP-0311 into tree structure or XML

Tags: java, xml, tap, asn.1

First of all, I've Googled this topic very much. I've tried to look and Bouncy Castle and Apache Harmony. But without any luck.

I'm trying to parse TAP-0311 (TAP3) files into a simple Java structure such as a tree or XML etc.

I have some TAP3 and a corresponding TAP3-0311.asn file containing the TAP files structure.

Can anyone help me on how I can parse a single TAP3 file in Java and print out it's content to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much out there on TAP3.  I found [this site](http://www.obj-sys.com/product-asn2csv.php), which is a commercial product for converting ASN.1 encoded data to CSV (some examples on the site are TAP3).  If you want to write your own you're going to need a parser for the ASN.1 syntax description and then a program that can load the syntax description and parse the input data... no small task for something as complex as ASN.1

If you can use Perl instead, there appears to be a [TAP3-Edit Module on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~mrjones/TAP3-Tap3edit/).

There's also a [What is TAP3 page at gsm.org](http://www.gsm.org/technology/roaming/billing-standards/what_is_tap_3.htm).

Comment: I work for the referenced company.  If you don't want to produce a CSV file, there is also asn1c, which generates Java classes corresponding to the ASN.1 types, and asn2xml, for producing XML data.